# Prove that two matrices are row equivalent if and only if they have the same null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be $m\times n$ matrices such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ and $B\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ have the same solution ($A,B$ have the same null space). I need to prove that given that knowledge, we can deduce that $A,B$ are row equivalent. 
How can I approach this?

Comment: Remember the row space is the orthogonal complement of the null space.

Comment: @Wintermute so it means the they have the same row space as well?and there for they are row equivalent?any chance you can write in a more formal way,it's just im in the begining of the course of linear algebra and I'm still struggling a little bit with formal proof.